# How to include ViewBag value into javascript in view of controller

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I have a controller view in an ASP.NET-MVC4 application, in which I have put a javascript for plotting purposes.

I want to get the value of `ViewBag` into that script. But it does not work.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var number =  @(Model.Last().Energie_E_Maschine_kwh).ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work', number],
      ['Eat', 2],
      ['Commute', 2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep', 7]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Here `ViewBag.test` is my value that I want to access from the controller. When I print or use the value of `ViewBag` outside the script, it works fine.

Number conversion from German to standard:

```
['Work', @(Model.Last().Energie_E_Maschine_kwh).toString("G2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)],
```

Comment: @StephenMuecke actuall if I put a constant value, for example 14 then script picks the value. But in my case I am accessing thei ViewBag value from sql server and I am working in german number system, in which comma is replaced instead of dot. I guess It was not working due that problem. This script doest not draw due to comma. Do you have any idea about how to convert commaa with dot.

Comment: @StephenMuecke If put `ViewBag.test= 14;` it works but If I access value from sql it does not

Comment: Try formating the number, for example ViewBag.test = yourNumericValue.ToString("G2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) so that 100,00 becomes 100.00

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have made changes in the question for number formatting in the end. but not worked

Comment: it turns an error that float cannot be converted to string. there is a red line under toString

Comment: I guess `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is used to convert time and date format not numbers.

Comment: `Float` can definitely be converted to a string. Its `.ToString(...)`, not `toString(...)`.

Comment: You should also use `.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` rather that "G2" in case its a large number and you get an exponential result.

Comment: @StephenMuecke it was required to include `using System.Globalization;` into system assemblies. now it worked. Number has been converted. It rounds off the data but not converstion.

Comment: my main problem is still there. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the quatations: `var number =  @(Model.Last().Energie_E_Maschine_kwh).ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`